# Как правильно отсортировать DOM-элементы по атрибуту?

Tags: javascript, html5

Классический "пузырёк" не работает - ноды не присваиваются:

```
for(var i = 0; i < List.childElementCount; i++){
    for(var j = List.childElementCount-1; j > i; j--){
        if (parseInt(List.childNodes[j-1].id) > parseInt(List.childNodes[j].id)){
            var Buf = List.childNodes[j-1];
            List.childNodes[j-1] = List.childNodes[j];
            List.childNodes[j] = Buf;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: List]

Пробовал `List.replaceChild` вместо присвоения - вообще список чистится.

**Как отсортировать ноды по их числовому id?**

*PS: Менять по атрибутам нодов - не вариант, надо объектами целиком, так как один из элементов может быть выбран (помечен другим font-weight и color) - это должно сохраниться при сортировке.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не правильно думаете, что если поменяли данные в св-ве `childNodes`, то это как-то скажется на `DOM-структуру`. Все ручками делать нужно

```js
const list = document.getElementById('List')

// функция сортировки
const sortListById = (list) => {
  const listElements = [...list.children] // превращаем NodeList в настоящий массив
  // сортируем
  const sortedListElements = listElements.sort((a, b) => (+a.id) - (+b.id))
  // очищаем родительский контейнер
  list.innerHTML = ''
  // вставляем элементы в новом порядке
  sortedListElements.forEach(el => list.appendChild(el))
}

const button = document.querySelector('button')
button.onclick = () => sortListById(list)
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <button>Сортировать</button>
  <div id='List'>
    <a id='9999' href='#'>9999</a>
    <a id='9998' href='#'>9998</a>
    <a id='7999' href='#'>7999</a>
    <a id='9591' href='#'>9591</a>
    <a id='1436' href='#'>1436</a>
    <a id='345' href='#'>345</a>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE**
`es5` синтаксис

```
var list = document.getElementById('List')

// функция сортировки
var sortListById = function (list) {
  var listElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(list.children); // превращаем NodeList в настоящий массив
  // сортируем
  var sortedListElements = listElements.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (+a.id) - (+b.id);
  })
  // очищаем родительский контейнер
  list.innerHTML = ''
  // вставляем элементы в новом порядке
  sortedListElements.forEach(function(el) {
    list.appendChild(el)
  });
}

var button = document.querySelector('button');
button.onclick = function () { sortListById(list); }
```

Comment: Не знаю... как ни присваиваю в отдельную переменную список childNodes, после list.innerHTML = ''; буферный список тоже пустой

Comment: @Iceman, как именно вы присваиваете? Добавил код для старого синтаксиса

Comment: Спасибо большое! Код из UPDATE работает. Хотя не понимаю почему первый вариант не срабатывал - запускал в Chromium 58

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')), // собираем массив из элементов, которые надо упорядочить по айди
    parent = document.querySelector('div'); // контейнер, в котором находятся элементы

while (parent.firstChild) { // очищаем контейнер от неупорядоченных элементов
  parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
}

arr.sort(function(a, b) { // сортируем массив элементов по атрибуту айди
  return parseFloat(a.id) - parseFloat(b.id);
})

arr.forEach(function(item) { // вставляем массив в контейнер
  parent.appendChild(item);
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="1" href="#">1</a>
  <a id="8" href="#">8</a>
  <a id="6" href="#">6</a>
  <a id="2" href="#">2</a>
  <a id="10" href="#">10</a>
  <a id="3" href="#">3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: очистку можно было сразу сделать как `parent.innerHTML = ''`, нет лишних переборов)))

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев сам не проверял, но пишут, что через `.innerHTML = ''` дольше чистится.

Comment: как же может быть дольше, когда у вас время растет от количества элементов в цикле. А тут вы просто говорите сотри все внутри :) При этом если работать с `removeChild` и иметь сохраненную ссылку на элемент DOM, а потом его удалить, ссылка останется, т.е. не удалится из памяти, значит будет занимать её. Все просто :) Ваш вариант тоже верный.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев проверку по скорости можно посмотреть тут: http://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-removechild